# Context menu paste

Tags: reactjs, angular, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am using tinymce in my application and would like to paste the copied content using context menu options. However, I don't see paste options in the documentation. Could you please someone provide the documentation or example?

```
Link: https://codepen.io/balukantu/pen/abEOvKr
```

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to do what you want on most modern browsers.

If you try to use the built in Cut/Copy/Paste toolbar buttons or menu options in TinyMCE you see this for most browsers:

> "Your browser doesn't support direct access to the clipboard. Please
> use the Ctrl+X/C/V keyboard shortcuts instead."

As the message from the editor states this is simply a limitation of what you can / cannot do directly via JavaScript in certain browsers.

IE11 does indeed allow access via legacy APIs but no other browser at present supports the clipboard APIs at all so the only way to copy what is in the clipboard is to use the keyboard.